# url manager yii

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, yii

These I've added as my following rules:

```
'search/do'=>'search/do',
'search/do/<town:.*?>'=>'search/do',
'search/do/<town:.*?>/<cat:.*?>'=>'search/do',
'search/do/<town:.*?>/<cat:.*?>/<scat:.*?>'=>'search/do',
```

the url search/do & search/do/chicago working fine. But search/do/chicago/restaurants gives an error for $_GET['cat'] (**undefined index cat**)

Comment: "do" is an action.. "search" is the conroller. So which one you want?

Comment: Is there any other rule in urlManager?

Comment: @FabianoLothor yes there is, but nothing related to search controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure the rules are in decreasing order of *specificity* . More specific rules should come first, followed by the lesser ones:

```
'search/do/<town:.*?>/<cat:.*?>/<scat:.*?>'=>'search/do',
'search/do/<town:.*?>/<cat:.*?>'=>'search/do',
'search/do/<town:.*?>'=>'search/do',
'search/do'=>'search/do',
```

The rules in your question matched `chicago/restaurants` to `$_GET['town']` because of the second rule : `'search/do/<town:.*?>'=>'search/do',` and it didn't navigate to the third rule. So you should have the specific ones first.